# How to interpret "5 weeks into my degree"?

Tags: prepositions, ambiguity, time

I was wondering whether it meant:

1. I started my degree 5 weeks ago
2. I finished my degree 5 weeks ago (I found this in an online dictionary)
3. I will be finishing my degree in 5 weeks

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We need some context in order to provide a correct interpretation. Where did you hear this? Who was saying it, and why? In fact, in the absence of other context, I would assume the person was referring to five weeks after he or she had started a degree program. For further guidance about how to use EL&U, please take the site [tour] and review the [help].

Comment: It almost certainly doesn't mean the third. It generally means the first, but there is ambiguity between the first and second options, which is why the preferred phrasing is "degree course" rather than just "degree".

Comment: Normally it would imply 5 weeks into studies for an advanced degree, but it's ambiguous (especially without any context).

Comment: Perhaps it's a matter of dialect, but I don't see any ambiguity (AuE) - of your choices, the word *into* only works with #1 for me. There might be a case for ambiguity between #2 and #3 if you had *from* in place of *into*. (Comments, @HotLicks and Deepak?)

Comment: @Lawrence - Consider that, with a college student (or recent grad) you have no clue (especially at this distance) as to dialect.  In particular, folks from India and nearby countries speak a vernacular that can put unexpected twists on seemingly unambiguous terms.  I can see someone intending to say something meaning "I'm five weeks into the job I got after my degree", for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I also see no ambiguity, it's only #1 "I started 5 weeks ago"

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguity that I see in the original sentence involves the issue of whether the word *degree* in the phrase "five weeks into my degree" means "degree program" (that is, "course of study leading to a degree") or "awarded degree." If the former meaning is intended, it seems clear to me that the meaning of the phrase is "I embarked on my degree program five weeks ago." If the latter meaning is intended, I think readers will remain in the dark until the speaker or writer clarifies what it means to be some number of weeks "into" an awarded degree.

With regard to unambiguously expressing each of the three ideas that the poster cites as possible interpretations of the original wording, I suggest the following formulations.

To express the idea "I started my degree five weeks ago," I would say

> five weeks into my degree program

To express the idea "I finished my degree five weeks ago," I would say

> five weeks after obtaining my degree

To express the idea "I will be finishing my degree in 5 weeks," I would say

> five weeks from completing my degree program